# What is ordered ordinal logit model?

Tags: spss, logit, ordered-logit

Is ordinal regression and ordered ordinal logit model the same? I read that there are different types of ordinal regression. How can I understand which type of ordinal regression should I use and analyze in SPSS in a simple way?

Comment: can you share the link where you read different type of ordinal regression it will be helpful as SPSS is performing only a single type of ordinal regression.

Comment: https://statistics.laerd.com/spss-tutorials/ordinal-regression-using-spss-statistics.php#procedure

Please go below to  'Test Procedure in SPSS Statistics' section. It is written in the second paragraph.... In addition, there is more than one type of ordinal regression that can be used to analyse ordinal dependent variables.....